# Can slow connection between client and server slowdown server?

Tags: performance, server, performance-testing, load-testing

I know the question might sound stupid, but, I really want to understand why not? Imagine a server needs to send 500 KB of data downstream and clients are downloading at 250 KBPS, server has to keep the connection alive for 2 seconds. Imagine there are a substantial number of request coming from these clients, threads are kept busy catering to these clients and the overall response time (even the ones with better connectivity) spikes up. Correct?

Comment: No. Explaining why is WAY too long for this forum

Comment: @symcbean can you give some pointers? Or at least point out a logical flow so that I can research myself.

Comment: https://blogs.akamai.com/2013/09/slow-dos-on-the-rise.html The above blog seems to suggest that slow client connection can bring down server. Although it talks about client sending small accept window, it can be really true in some cases. Can someone explain why not?